# how to write a variables's content to a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [firefox: How to enable local javascript to read/write files on my PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846045/firefox-how-to-enable-local-javascript-to-read-write-files-on-my-pc)

Consider the JavaScript code:

```
var body=" ";
body=body+/*some string*/
```

I want some simple way to write this content (`var body` in this code) to a file in local computer.

Please help me out in doing this job.

Thanks

Comment: didn't get you? what you want??, do : `body +=body+/*some string*/`

Comment: Javascript running in a browser doesn't have access to the underlying file system for security reasons, but this could be accomplished if you're talking about server-side JS (such as node.js). Are you? :)

Comment: @Chris - not strictly true. Permissions can be given and IE can use WSH FileSystemObject in HTA

Answer (score 1):

Due to security restrictions you can not write local files using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript on a web page cannot write a file to the local computer.

There is some scope for this in HTML 5, but it's not widely supported yet: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Comment: Except cookies. Cookies are also files (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

For this, In your script section add:

```
try{var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');} catch(err){}

This will promp user to enable Activex.
Then you can run any of the command using:

wsh.Run("notepad.exe"); //OR
wsh.Run("echo asdfasf sFAS  > a");
```

may be it works for you
**NOTE: i used ActiveXObject that means it works in IE only**

Comment: thanks. but echo command not working in wsh.Run(); all other commands are working. please help

Comment: i am using 

wsh.Run("echo asdfd > C:\Users\Srikanth\Desktop\Newfolder\aa.txt");