# Using "FSO" in Javascript, how to write a variables's content to a file?

Tags: javascript, activex, filesystemobject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write a variables's content to a file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097075/how-to-write-a-variabless-content-to-a-file-in-javascript)

I have this piece of code to create a text file.
How can I write to this text file?

```
function makefile() { 

    var fso; 

    var thefile;

    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    thefile=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\tmp\\MyFile.txt",true);

    thefile.close()
}
```

Comment: Dup of [this asked by you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097075/how-to-write-a-variabless-content-to-a-file-in-javascript)

Comment: This is only a partial duplicate of that question at best; it focuses on using the FSO support. Supposedly this much already creates a file. (There may already be duplicates, the newer tags should help. In any case, if you do opt for a duplicate close -- please *don't pick* the other question as the duplicate :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
makefile();

function makefile () {

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        thefile=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\temp\\MyFile.txt",true);

    thefile.WriteLine('abc');
    thefile.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind this will only work in IE with the correct "relaxed" security permissions.

All the information can be found under [FileSystemObject Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When you `CreateTextFile` (or `OpenAsTextStream` in write mode) you get a [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object back which has a `WriteLine` method, among others. Please see the examples for "the code".

Happy coding.