# Is it possible to write text in .txt file using angularjs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phonegap

Is it possible to write text in .txt file using javascript or angularjs or phonegap without using any backend

Comment: There should be *something* that writes to a file server-side. Whatever is capable of doing that would be called a backend, "by definition".

Comment: If by any chance you use Windows you can use JavaScript for scripting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106312/using-fso-in-javascript-how-to-write-a-variabless-content-to-a-file (could be even duplicate, but I strongly suspect you are asking about something very different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to write text in .txt file using javascript or angularjs without using any backend

#### Short answer - **No**

#### detailed answer:

You must store somewhere your file and it can be done by server side only.

The client side (AngularJs in your case) loads vendors/bundle sources on web browsers and it doesn't have any access to your file system.

---

I believe [Chrome extensions: fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) is not your case

---

> is it possible in phonegap?

Well, its a hybrid mobile infrastructure and you have [plugins to access mobile filesystem](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Comment: is it possible in phonegap ?

Comment: @SangramBadi is there any reason you did not bother trying to google for "phonegap write file"?