# Ajax - Knowing if file download was correctly sent from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have an extjs ajax function that send a form to the server which returns a file to download with the correct `Content-Disposition ="attachment; filename='test.zip'"` header. The file can be downloaded with the normal file download window of the browser. However, the success callback function of the ajax request is not triggered and the ajax is pending indefinately waiting for a response.

Is there a way to tell the ajax function that the file was correctly sent from the server or not?

```
  exportLayer = function(node_id){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      method: "GET",
      form: "exportForm",
      url: "/basqui/layer/shapefile/export/" + node_id + "/",
      success: function(r){
                  html = Ext.decode(r.responseText).html
                  Ext.get('pageContent').update(html);
                  },
    });
  }
```

Comment: if you just return the url itself you can simply do `window.location='path/to/download'`

Comment: its a memory file, a zip created with data from database, not a file on server disk

Comment: so skip the ajax and just use `window.location`

Comment: the ajax is used to submit the form needed for the file creation

Comment: and why can't you just get the values and add them to the GET? ajax is not intended for file downloads. Or simply submit the form, browser won't redirect if it's a zipp output at server

Comment: because if the form as errors, Ajax will return it with some error messages without reloading the page. AJAX can only handle json response as far as I know, but I cant return file and json in same time?

Comment: you could return json and a file as Base64 encoded data in json property, when you could process the file as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `binary` configuration property of `Ext.Ajax.request` and in the response you would get 
the binary data inside **`responseBytes`** property.

For example loading jpeg image:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: "/path/to/image/test.jpg",
      success: function(xhr) {
          var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, xhr.responseBytes));

          var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
              src: 'data:application/jpeg;base64,' + b64encoded
          });
          // add image somewhere
          ...                
      }
 });
```

Comment: not sure it would be efficient with large file, and how can I send it to the download application of the browser?

Comment: returning json with validation results and file data base64 encoded would be inefficient for big files, but for small is works. How to download the binary data received via [xhr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752984/html5-file-api-downloading-file-from-server-and-saving-it-in-sandbox), FileAPI and XHR2. But if you want to validate form and then download a file without FileAPI&XHR2  make it in 2 steps: 1. xhr validating the form and 2. receiving the validation results and and being sure all is correct inside the xhr response run the `window.location` dedicated to file download.

Comment: my answer mostly was about why your `Ext.Ajax.request` _is not triggered and the ajax is pending indefinately waiting for a response._ Cause request was made to receive the binary data but   `binary` configuration option was missed.